# Running an infinite loop worker in python with a HTTP health check endpoint

Tags: python

I have a python project that consumes messages from an AWS SQS queue and performs tasks. It does this by constantly trying to get messages from the queue in an infinite loop and performing operations on each message when they're found.

I'd like to deploy this code in a docker container and would like to integrate a health check to ensure certain things are working.

I am trying to understand what the best way is to integrate a light weight webserver alongside the infinite loop to serve a `/health-check` endpoint.

The main option I have considered and tried to implement is to run a webserver along side the infinite loop. I have tried this using popular libraries like flask/fastapi, however it seems like they both block the main thread, requiring the worker to run in its own thread.

This seems to introduce further complexity by requiring the queue consumer to also handle thread errors and sigint messages from the main thread.

Is there a simpler way to introduce a health check without requiring the implementation of thread<>thread message handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the lack of responses (and downvote) I ended up just continuing with doing things in parallel.

I used python's `multiprocessing` library to put a fastapi endpoint in a separate process. I then call `terminate` on the process when the long running worker process exits for any reason.

I am not handling errors in the separate process since the healthcheck is very simple and if it fails, the entire container will restart (thanks Docker).

I am still looking for a more elegant solution if anyone has any experience here.